# jsf databinding does not work

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to create a page using richfaces, I created the following field

```
<h:inputText value="#{petTest.pet.name}"/>
```

faces-config:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>petTest</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>petstore.PetTest</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

managed bean:

```
package petstore;

public class PetTest {
    private Pet pet;

    public Pet getPet(){
        return pet;
    }

    public void setPet(Pet pet){
        this.pet = pet;
    }
}
```

But I get a field and within it the literal value `#{petTest.pet.name}` instead of the value of the field. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JSF version? JSP or Facelets? Which server? Which JAR's in `WEB-INF/lib`? Did you ever touch `/lib` folder of server? How does `web.xml` look like? Can you post the *minimum* JSP/XHTML page which still reproduces this problem? Please edit and update your question to include more detail.

Comment: I dont see how JSP or facelets/which server/which jar has to do anything with my problem, this is a strange request from your side... imagine that i am using tomcat, would this problem ever happen because i am using tomcat??? if i dont have any jar in my lib folder would the application ever run?? I mentioned that the applicatin is running but the value is not translated properly

Comment: Uhm, how about just answering the questions in the comment? You want help? Help us to help you.

Comment: That's just not possible what you are experiencing. Seems like some configuration problems. Is there any error logs? Check the server.log

Answer (score -1):

Is your *h:inputText* part of a h:form like this:

```
<h:form id="formId">
   ..
   <h:inputText value="#{petTest.pet.name}"/>
   ..
</h:form>
```

Without a form *h:inputText* is not working.

Comment: This can't be the cause of the problem of seeing `#{petTest.pet.name}` in the input field in the webbrowser (the concrete problem the OP is struggling with).